# Скриншот окна браузера

Tags: php, imagemagick, javascript, perl

**Можно использовать:**

php, perl, imagemagick, gd, shell

**Нельзя использовать:**

Сторонние библиотеки и программы. Нужна именно суть реализации подобного.

**Задача:**

Сделать скриншот урла по нажатию на кнопку в браузере.

**Пример:**

```
<script>
function shot() {
var url = 'http://ya.ru';
...//ajax
}
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="shot();">
```

Как обустроить frontend я знаю и с этим проблем никаких нет. Вопрос как можно указанными средствами сделать скриншот с урла.

Идеи вроде поставить vm не подходят, нужно делать все моментально, запрос ушел - ответ пришел, без особых задержек.

**Идеи гугла:**

1. Через shell, используя firefox

bash:

```
firefox URL
scrot -d 5 OUT.png
```

Недостатки: если на сервере нет x-ов или прав у юзера нет, то все обломается

1. Через IE COM

Реализацию можно найти на хабре или воспользоваться php.net

Недостатки: только под винды, а нужно под линух

Надеюсь, что решение есть, просто я не умею использовать гугл :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не пойму я, как это вы хотите обойтись без «сторонних библиотек и программ» — самому полностью писать рендерную машину? Но раз ImageMagick вам не сторонний, то полагаю, и [webkit-qt](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKit) тоже сойдет :)

1. Если все-таки есть иксы и можно использовать браузер, то лучше коннектиться к файрфоксу через [MozRepl](https://github.com/bard/mozrepl/wiki).
2. Если хочется обойтись без иксов (точнее, без рисования на экране), то можно задействовать [xvfb](http://www.xfree86.org/4.0.1/Xvfb.1.html) или [vncserver](http://www.realvnc.com/products/free/4.1/man/vncserver.html).
3. Если хочется обойтись без целого браузера, то можно брать какой-нибудь headless движок: [phantomjs](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/), [watin](http://watin.org/), [htmlunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)

Вот вам пример для ориентировки: [CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/). Удачи.

Comment: Примерно это и нужно было! Спасибо :)